# Switching from one column to two columns on a frame

Tags: beamer, width

I am writing a presentation, and would like to use the following layout:

On top, there is one big box spannign the whole page width, below, there are two boxes side by side.

My problem is that the left and right edges of the upper box and the lower boxes won't line up.
I already have tried various options such as totalwidth and textwidth, but I can't make it work.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usecolortheme{orchid}

\begin{document} 
  \begin{frame} 
    \begin{block}{Single Column} \vspace{4em} \end{block} 
    \begin{columns} 
      \begin{column}{.5\textwidth} 
        \begin{block}{Two Columns} \vspace{4em} \end{block} 
      \end{column} 
      \begin{column}{.5\textwidth} 
        \begin{block}{Two Columns} \vspace{4em} \end{block} 
      \end{column} 
    \end{columns} 
  \end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

[image: rendering of latex]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usecolortheme{orchid}

\newsavebox{\squaredblocktext}
\setbeamertemplate{block begin}{
    \par\vskip\medskipamount%
    \makebox[\dimexpr\textwidth-1.5ex\relax][l]{%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep*=.75ex]{block title}
            \usebeamerfont*{block title}\insertblocktitle%
        \end{beamercolorbox}}%
        \begin{lrbox}{\squaredblocktext}%
            \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}%
                \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block body}{\vskip-.25ex}{\vskip-.75ex}\vbox{}%
            }

            \setbeamertemplate{block end}{
            \end{minipage}%
        \end{lrbox}%
        {\parskip0pt\par}%
        \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block title}{}
        {\ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block body}{}{\nointerlineskip\vskip-0.5pt}}%
        \usebeamerfont{block body}%
        \makebox[\dimexpr\textwidth-1.5ex\relax][l]{%
            \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep*=.75ex,vmode]{block body}%
                \usebox{\squaredblocktext}
            \end{beamercolorbox}%
        }\vskip\smallskipamount%
    }

\begin{document} 
  \begin{frame} 
    \begin{block}{Single Column} \vspace{4em} \end{block} 
    \begin{columns}[onlytextwidth, T]
      \begin{column}{.45\textwidth} 
        \begin{block}{Two Columns} \vspace{4em} \end{block} 
      \end{column} 
      \begin{column}{.45\textwidth} 
        \begin{block}{Two Columns} \vspace{4em} \end{block} 
      \end{column} 
    \end{columns} 
  \end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

[image]